# Get info about latest created and completed tasks in asana

Tags: asana, asana-connect

I need to maintain list if all user's incomplete tasks with asana API.

Right now, the best solution I came up with is polling asana for every X minutes and use `/tasks` with `completed_since` filter. However this is inefficient, since I have to perform exactly one call for every workspace.

The next thing I tried was looking into `/events` API, but events are generated only for projects and tasks. I got about 25 projects so it isn't the best solution either.

Is there any way I could check for updates efficiently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, "exactly one call per workspace" is as good as it's gonna get - we scope each request to a workspace (in fact, it's likely that in the future each API call will need to be *explicitly* scoped to a workspace). It's a hard IP boundary, so basically we never "mix" data from different workspaces (except for certain exceptions, like "listing the workspaces I'm in").

If you're specifically only looking for *updates* to tasks, you could also use `modified_since`.